# Create a variable in data.table with variable saved in other variable

Tags: r, data.table, data-cleaning

I have very simple problem. Let's suppose I have data table:

```
dt = data.table(a = rnorm(10), b = rnrom(10))
```

I wanted to create a new variable in `dt` like `c = b * 2`. But I wanted to take both variable name `b` and `c` from other variables stored in string. Example

```
newvar = "c"
var = "b"
```

I can easily do this without using data table like this:

```
setDF(dt)
dt[newvar] = dt[var] * 2
```

I wanted to know, how can I do the same in data.table package syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you wanted, but is this what you're looking for : 

library(data.table)
dt = data.table(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
dt$c <- dt$b * 2

Answer (score 1):

We can use *get*:

```
dt[, (newvar) := get(var) * 2 ]
```